# Incoming Call Hold Issue using jssip libraries

Tags: jssip

## Incoming Call Hold Issue

```
$('#hold_audio_btn_1').click(function () {
    session.hold();
    isCallOnHold = true;
});

Above piece of code is working fine for Outgoing call, not working with an incoming call.
When i tried to keep the incoming call on hold, getting a reverse incoming call from the number which i tried to keep on Hold.
```

I need Solution for this issue please response.thank you in advance.